# Joining and replacing columns multiple times

Tags: r, left-join

I have a dataframe with a lot of columns with abbreviations. I'm trying to replace the columns with their full name.

A minimal reproducible example:

```
category <- data.frame(short = c("TOM", "BAN", "APP", "PEA"),
  name = c("tomato", "banana", "apple", "pear"))

df <- data.frame(col1 = c("TOM", "TOM", "TOM", "APP", "TOM"),
             col2 = c("APP", "TOM", "TOM", "PEA", "PEA"),
             col3 = c("TOM", "PEA", "PEA", "TOM", "BAN"))

  col1 col2 col3
1  TOM  APP  TOM
2  TOM  TOM  PEA
3  TOM  TOM  PEA
4  APP  PEA  TOM
5  TOM  PEA  BAN
```

Now, I would like my dataframe to just contain the full names of the products. I can get it to work with left_joins, selecting and renaming, but this code is getting out of hand pretty rapidly with a lot of columns.

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  left_join(category, by = c("col1" = "short")) %>% 
  select(-col1) %>% 
  rename(col1 = name) %>% 
  left_join(category, by = c("col2" = "short")) %>% 
  select(-col2) %>% 
  rename(col2 = name) %>% 
  left_join(category, by = c("col3" = "short")) %>% 
  select(-col3) %>% 
  rename(col3 = name) 

    col1   col2   col3
1 tomato  apple tomato
2 tomato tomato   pear
3 tomato tomato   pear
4  apple   pear tomato
5 tomato   pear banana
```

I think (hope?) there's a better solution for it, but I'm unable to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option is to create a named vector

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
v1 <- deframe(category)
```

and then use that to match and replace the values

```
df1 <- df %>%
          mutate(across(everything(), ~ v1[.]))
```

-output

```
df1
#   col1   col2   col3
#1 tomato  apple tomato
#2 tomato tomato   pear
#3 tomato tomato   pear
#4  apple   pear tomato
#5 tomato   pear banana
```

It can be also done with `recode` using similar way

```
df %>%
     mutate(across(everything(), ~ recode(., !!! v1)))
```

---

Or using `base R`, create the named vector with `setNames`, loop over the columns with `lapply` and replace those values and assign it back

```
v1 <- with(category, setNames(name, short))
df1 <- df
df1[] <- lapply(df, function(x) v1[x])
```

Or convert to `matrix` (a `matrix` is a `vector` with `dim` attributes)

```
df1[1] <- v1[as.matrix(df)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using `factor`

```
df[] <- factor(
  u <- unlist(df),
  labels = with(category, name[match(sort(unique(u)), short)])
)
```

or a shorter one via `setNames`

```
df[]<-with(category,setNames(name,short))[unlist(df)]
```

which gives

```
> df
    col1   col2   col3
1 tomato  apple tomato
2 tomato tomato   pear
3 tomato tomato   pear
4  apple   pear tomato
5 tomato   pear banana
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the data in long format such that all the values are in one column which is easy to join with `category` dataframe and then get data back in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -row, names_to = 'col', values_to = 'short') %>%
  left_join(category, 'short') %>%
  select(-short) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = col, values_from = name)  %>%
  select(-row)

#   col1   col2   col3  
#  <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
#1 tomato apple  tomato
#2 tomato tomato pear  
#3 tomato tomato pear  
#4 apple  pear   tomato
#5 tomato pear   banana
```